# HTML textarea alignment

Tags: php, html, css, alignment, cpu-word

Suppose I have textarea filled with following text

> employee/company/salary
>
> john/microsoft/12.000
>
> michael/citrusdata/15.000

How can I align each column vertically so I get following text:

> employee__________company__________salary
>
> john______________microsoft__________12.000
>
> michael___________citrusdata__________15.000

In this example I used underscores to specify whitespaces, thought to write a simple function like `nl2br()` to replace '/' with one or many tab characters but it wont be a consistent solution, guess I need to read text line by line and considering the length of every word, I need to replace '/' with enough whitespace but dont have any idea how to code it, is there any other way?

Comment: Why a textarea and not discreet inputs ?

Comment: There are no columns in textarea

Comment: I want to get second output, because in my local database, there are textareas and I write my records from database to word document so it is needed to be aligned

Comment: if you create text boxes that are the same width and height as each other and float them left, you can then text align left and it will look like its in a table without borders.

Comment: I dont want to use table kinda structure because if I use, I need to add extra tables to my database and I want to keep it simple, with some function I want to align my text in the textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you will output the textarea content outside the textarea itself, else you will need to use js alternative. My answer uses php :)
So, you may use the [sprintf function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) that allows left or right padding.

Just split your content to get an array of lines

```
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
```

Take care of a eventual empty last entry (if your content end with a \n)

Then

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $items = explode("/", $line) ;
    echo sprintf("%-15s%-15s%-15s", $items[0], $items[1], $items[2]) . "<br/>";
}
```

"%-15" tells to left-pad with 15 empty spaces.
It works on console, but you have to nl2br it before echoing in web pages !

This is sample, so you have to add error testing (lines with only one / for example).

Comment: thanks Armage, appreciated :)  I like this kind solutions

edit: yeah you're right, I'll use output to write it to word document

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the width of each column like 50 characters for each or any desired width. let say it `$COLUMN_WIDTH = 100;`
find length of the column value (string) than subtract it from fixed length like 
`$COUNT_SPACES_TO_INSERT = $COLUMN_WIDTH - strlen($COLUMN_STR);`
Than insert $COUNT_SPACES_TO_INSERT number of spaces it will solve your issue.

Comment: Can you give further explanation please, I'm newbie to all php and html, and I'm not sure if its the solution or not

Comment: Thanks Muzammil, Armage gave an example that I wanted, I was looking for php solution